# Command for posting user's avatar

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['av'])
async def avatar(ctx, *,  avamember : discord.Member = None):
    userAvatarUrl = avamember.avatar_url
    await ctx.send(userAvatarUrl)
```

I would like the command to post the mentioned user's avatar. If no user is mentioned, it should post my own avatar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the previous answer says, you need to put an if statement if you didn't mention the user, but I updated the code to something good (like put it into an embed to make it more prettier):

```py
@bot.command(aliases = ['av'])
async def avatar(ctx, member : discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        member = ctx.author # It will show your avatar if you didn't mention a user (if statement)
        embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{member.name}'s avatar", color = 0x2F3136)
        em.set_image(url = member.avatar_url) # Shows the avatar
        em.set_footer(text = f'Requested by {ctx.author}', icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

Thank me later :D

Comment: This command will execute nothing if `member` is not None, correct? You did not include an else/elif statement.

Comment: it did execute, It worked perfectly though

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `member` is `None`, then use the avatar of the `ctx.author`:

```py
@bot.command(aliases=['av'])
async def avatar(ctx, *,  member : discord.Member = None):
if member == None:
    user_avatar_url = ctx.author.avatar_url
else: 
    user_avatar_url = member.avatar_url
await ctx.send(user_avatar_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
@bot.command(aliases=["av"])
async def avatar(ctx, *, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member!=None:
        pfp = member.avatar_url
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{member.name}'s profile picture!")
        embed.set_image(url=pfp)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        author = ctx.message.author
        pfp = author.avatar_url
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{author.name}'s profile picture!")
        embed.set_image(url=pfp)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: i have made this based on everyone's code sent here. Thank you for the references! Hope this works. :). I have a strong feeling that it can be further simplified. Any suggestions are welcome (excuse me for my bad English)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).